# Logic Error; TextView returns even after setting to null

Tags: java, android

I have a logic error in a simple android app;

I have 3 `Buttons` (Permute, Clear and GC), 1 `EditText` and a `TextView`. When the Permute button is clicked it sends the text in the `EditText` box to a method from another class and sets the returned value to the `TextView`. The returned value is just gibberish text.

[image: 1]

When I click the *Clear*, it clears the current contents of the `EditText` box  and the `TextView`; (by setting the contents to a null string "").

[image: 2]

**However when I click Permute with new values in the textBox, the old (cleared) text returns along with the newer text below**

[image: 3]

Here's the code:

package com.mobinga.string;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import com.mob.string.Perm; 

public class MoPermActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
    Button btn;
    Button btn2;
    Button btn3;
    EditText et;
    TextView tv;
    Vibrator vi;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        btn =  (Button) findViewById(R.id.Permute);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Clear);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.GC);
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn3.setOnClickListener(this);
        et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Text);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }


    public void onClick(View view){
        switch(view.getId()){

        case R.id.Permute:
            vi =  (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                vi.vibrate(50);
                tv.setText(Perm.perm(et.getText().toString()));
            break;

        case R.id.Clear:
            vi =  (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                et.setText("");
                tv.setText("");
                vi.vibrate(50);
            break;

        case R.id.GC:
            vi =  (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            GC();
            vi.vibrate(50);
        }
    }


    public static void GC(){
        Log.d("Permute","Calling GC");
        System.gc();
    }


}
```

**How do I properly and completely clear the contents of TextView, and stop it from returning? Simply put : My problem is that the supposedly cleared contents of the TextView return back even after clearing.**

**Edit** if necessary here's the Perm Class

```
package com.mob.string;

public class Perm {
    static String v = "";
     static void permute(int level, String permuted, boolean used[], String original) {
            int length = original.length();
            if (level == length) {
                v +=permuted+"\n";
            } else {
                for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    if (!used[i]) {
                        used[i] = true;
                        permute(level + 1, permuted + original.charAt(i), used, original);
                        used[i] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    public String perm(String s){
        boolean used[] = {false, false, false, false, false,false,false};
        permute(0, "", used, s);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: if instead of clearing, you set to a different arbitrary string (say, the current time in MilliSeconds or something) what shows up?

Comment: It still returns the old content with the new content appended after clicking `Permute`.

Comment: Ok..I've merged the answers into this question. Thanks for fixing up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

v is never reset.

```
    public String perm(String s){
        v = "";
        boolean used[] = {false, false, false, false, false,false,false};
        permute(0, "", used, s);
        return v;
    }
```

However I don't see why v even exists to be honest. I would of passed it through the recursive calls.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what the calss Perm is you are using but why not just try

```
tv.setText(et.getText().toString());
```

EDIT:

You should try setting it t a String variable first.

```
String editText = et.getText.toString();
```

then pass it to your TextView

```
tv.setText(editText);
```

Comment: I'm talking of how to clear the TextView without the previous text coming back?

Comment: I'ts not working bro, My question is how to **completely clear the contents of TextView**

Comment: @AlvinThen It doesn't work, it comes back again when I click the permute button with others added.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the problem lies in your Perm class - here you've got a static String, which isn't cleared anywhere (just appended). If you hold state in your class, make this "v" string a normal field and instantiate your class when needed.

Comment: Can you expatiate on this? Thanks.

Comment: In other words: it makes no sense to use static methods when you need to hold the state (in your variable v). Make them normal methods and make instances when needed. It will clean up your solution a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Store the state of the string in the `Activity`, pass it into the `Perm` class when you want to append values to it, and then clear the stored string at the same time you clear your `TextView`.

Or make a method in the `Perm` class called `clearString` which sets `v = ""`, and call it when you clear the `TextView`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the text in TextViews by setting text "" and clearing v value in Perm class. That should do the trick.